# Search box in Header using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place a search text box on the right hand side of the header and I can't seem to figure out how to do it using Bootstrap 2.0.1.
The code I am trying is

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1 class="span2">
        Parts
    </h1>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on">
                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="search" class="span3" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it the search text box is not being pushed to the right with the spans and offsets and the line on the bottom of the header is not being pushed to the bottom of the  tag.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `float: right` to the first div tag nested within `.page-header` works for me. You also need to remember to [clear your floats](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/), this is the reason the line at bottom of the header is not being pushed to the bottom of the tag.

So adding the following CSS would resolve your problem:

```
.page-header {
    overflow: hidden;    /* clear floats */     
}

.page-header div {
    float: right;        /* float search content right */          
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zds9/**

#### Edit

For some reason, as pointed out by @PlTaylor, the input field wraps onto a new linein Chrome. This can be fixed using the following CSS:

```
.input-prepend input {
    float: left;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zds9/1/**

Comment: This is really close, but the search icon should also be in line with the text box.

Comment: @PlTaylor Ok, see my amended answer - I'm not sure why chrome is showing that behavour

Comment: I neglected to say that I was doing all my testing in chrome.  thanks for your help.

Comment: @PlTaylor no problem, I should have checked in all browsers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
​input {
    float: right;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dXJb8/

Or you can use `position: fixed;` to set the location of your search box.

http://jsfiddle.net/dXJb8/1/

Comment: I added the bootstrap css files to your fiddles...as you can see they still don't turn out great http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/eB7MQ/ http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/sdPr5/